# How to fix JavaScript that automatically appends ?coolIrisSearch= + search term when enter is pressed

Tags: jquery, html, forms

My site is [here](http://bfcards.edicypages.com/)

When searching, the site auto-refreshes unexpectedly. The intended behavior is to initialize a search just as the user types enter - similar if you click on the search link instead of hitting enter. Instead what it does is it refreshes and appends ?coolIrisSearch= + search term to the url. Any ideas/code for a fix?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#cooliris input").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        $("#cooliris a#searchCooliris").click();
        return false;
    }
});    

doCoolIrisSearch = function() {
    cooliris.embed.setFeedURL( 'http%3A%2F%2Fpipes.yahooapis.com%2Fpipes%2Fpipe.run%3FSearch%3D'+encodeURIComponent($('#coolIrisSearch').val())+'%26_id%3D5f4545ce4062c36e4c5d9a8763b3167e%26_render%3Drss' );
    filter();
};
```

It looks like the keydown function here in your Home_Page.js file isn't actually clicking the searchCooliris control properly.  To clarify your question, clicking search yields results, but typing the return key does not.  Did you write Home_page.js or did you get it from somewhere else?

Comment: I partially wrote it and got the enter key from somewhere else

Comment: What happens if you trigger the link itself: $("#search").click();

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. It still refreshes and attaches ?coolIrisSearch=abyssal to the url.